# React/Redux dispatch function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using 'react-fileupload' to upload files on my server. In case of success I receive response with content of this file. So in one component I want to upload file and change stores state and in another component I want to show that data.

But i don't know why my dispatch function doesn't work.

Component with uploader:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FileUpload from 'react-fileupload';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateOverview } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const options = {
      baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload_file',
      chooseAndUpload: true,
      uploadSuccess: function(res) {
        console.log('success');
        updateOverview(res.data);
      },
      uploadError: function(err) {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <FileUpload options={options} ref="fileUpload">
          <button
            className="yellow darken-2 white-text btn-flat"
            ref="chooseAndUpload">
            Upload
          </button>
        </FileUpload>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ updateOverview }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Component where data is shown:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Overview extends Component {
  renderContent() {
    console.log(this.props.overview);
    if (!this.props.overview) {
      return <div> Upload file!</div>;
    }
    return this.props.overview;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Overview</h1>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps({ overview }) {
  return { overview };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Overview);
```

Action creator:

```
import { FETCH_OVERVIEW } from './types';

export function updateOverview(data) {
  return { type: FETCH_OVERVIEW, payload: data };
}
```

reducer index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import overviewReducer from './overviewReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  overview: overviewReducer
});
```

overviewReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_OVERVIEW } from '../actions/types';
export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_OVERVIEW:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: you are directly calling the action `updateOverview`, please try with `this.props.updateOverview`

Comment: I see from the docs that bindActionCreators takes a function or object. Maybe try taking the brackets away from updateOverview in the bindActionCreators parameters since it's being imported as a function?

Comment: { updateOverview } it means updateOverview:updateOverview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

Your `Header` component already knows how to create action.
Considering the your `Home` component need ,your don't need of `bindActionCreators`.

The correct way to do this.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        callUpdateOverview: () => {
            dispatch({ updateOverview });
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `Header` render method :

```
this.props.updateOverview(res.data);
```

EDIT :

In your `Home` Component `render` method,

```
       const homeThis = this; //save `this` object to some variables
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

       const options = {
            baseUrl: ..,
            chooseAndUpload: ..,
            uploadSuccess: function (res) {
                homeThis.props.callUpdateOverview();// call using `homeThis`          
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            }
        };
```

Comment: With this new mapDispatchToProps I still got an error:
this.props.updateOverview is not a function

Comment: @Ernst Check the EDIT.You need to save your `this` object and use it to call method.

Comment: I want to add that with your mapDispatchToProps function still got the same error)
So I've just left the original version of mapDispatchToProps function and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling

```
updateOverview(res.data);
```

actually which should be called like,

```
this.props.updateOverview(res.data);
```

Because, the redux will listen only to the dispatch bound actions, so to enable that, we use `connect` function from `react-redux` package, so that redux will know to update itself upon the action execution.

`connect` will bind your action to the component props on `this.props`, so it is very essential to use `this.props.action()` and not just `action()`

Comment: I tried 'this.props.updateOverview(res.data);' before but I've got an error:
this.props.updateOverview is not a function

Comment: can you please console `this.props` inside the `uploadSuccess` function and share what you are getting.?

Comment: @RaghavGarg In the `options` there is diff `this` bounded

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, Yeah, I noticed that, which was because of using `function` keyword, and also thought of the solution you wote in your answer, but i was just confused by the error, it says `not a function`. but it should give the error `undefined property props on 'this'`, thats why just wanted to confirm with OP, if he is getting something there.